# Facebook tag videos

Tags: php, facebook

I'm looking for some advice on if the following is possible

1. I know it's possible to upload videos via the facebook API, but is it also possible to tag users to those videos? It seems you can with photos, just not videos?
2. Is it possible to run an application on my facebook account which a visitor can give permissions to access their account video section, instead of having the user install the application to their account?

Here's what I'm trying to do

Video archive -> User visits a profile with an application installed, selects something, and the application then posts the video to it's own video section on the account that's stored on facebook, and tags the user who requested it

I'm basically wanting to bypass having the user install the application on their profile, and trying to have just one application running on a "host" profile.

If that makes sense, if not, please request some more information. The facebook API system is pretty much a minefield for new developers

Comment: Any update on this? I would like to tag a friend in a video uploaded to Facebook in one of my iPhone application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/) it does not currently seem possible to tag a user in a video. Facebook are still migrating their old APIs to the new Graph API format, so it seems likely that this will be an option in the future.